# Existe um pedido oficial para alterar o nome do país "Turquia" em Português?

Tags: ortografia, pronúncia, estrangeirismos

Pelo que li recentemente ([neste post do Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78164/are-there-other-countries-besides-t%C3%BCrkiye-that-insist-their-name-be-written-in-e)), existe um movimento oficial do governo turco requisitando que o nome do país seja alterado de *Turkey* (em Inglês) para *Türkiye* (pedido, aliás, [já aceito pelo governo norte-americano](https://www.dw.com/en/us-officially-changes-spelling-of-turkey-to-turkiye/a-64301304)).

Ainda de acordo com a minha compreensão ([lendo esta notícia](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-61671913)) a intenção é que o país fosse conhecido como *Türkiye* internacionalmente, mas fico pensando se o mesmo vale para o Português?

Isto posto, pergunto:

1. Existe um pedido oficial para que o país até então conhecido como *Turquia* (em Português) tenha seu nome alterado?
2. Caso positivo para qual nome? Assumindo que seja mesmo *Türkiye*, como ficaria a pronúncia no idioma de Camões (e de Machado de Assis, para termos ambos os *dialetos* cobertos na pergunta)?

Comment: Pelo Google não sai nenhum.

Comment: Acho que o "problema" era que o nome era o mesmo do pássaro. Essa questão não existe em português.

Comment: [A pergunta anterior](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78161/why-is-turkey-campaigning-to-get-their-name-changed-to-t%c3%bcrkiye-in-english-but-no), da qual nasceu essa, indica que sim, por exemplo: «In the future, Türkiye is to be used **in all foreign languages**, including German. Focus is on the English language, not only because of its international importance.» Mas como não tenho prova específica para português, levas um comentário e não uma resposta.

Comment: @Artefacto em ingles turkey = fiasco, fracaso (e peru)

Comment: In English, it will not be: Türkiye. It will be: Turkiye. We don't use the umlaut or other accent marks in English, generally speaking. I doubt that Turkey wants Turkiye because Turkey means peru in English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um pedido oficial específico para um país lusófono não parece ter sido feito, mas o desejo está claramente expressado na [circular (PDF)](https://www.resmigazete.gov.tr/eskiler/2021/12/20211204-5.pdf) presidencial:

[image]

[Traduzido](https://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/exports-to-be-labeled-made-in-turkiye-169885) como:

> “In this context, within the scope of strengthening the ‘Türkiye’ brand, in all kinds of activities and correspondence, especially in official relations with other states and international institutions and organizations, necessary sensitivity will be shown on the use of the phrase ‘Türkiye’ instead of phrases such as ‘Turkey,’ ‘Turkei,’ ‘Turquie’ etc.”

Ou, em tradução livre da versão em inglês:

> Neste contexto, dentro do escopo do fortalecimento da marca "Türkiye", em todos os tipos de atividades e correspondência, especialmente em relações oficiais com outros estados e instituições internacionais e organizações, a sensibilidade necessária será mostrada no uso da frase "Türkiye" ao invés de frases como "Turkey", "Turkei", "Turquie", etc."

Que explicitamente não se restringe ao nome do país em inglês.

Além disso, a versão em português das páginas das Embaixadas turcas em [Lisboa](http://lisbon.emb.mfa.gov.tr/Mission) e em [Luanda](http://luanda.be.mfa.gov.tr/Mission) usam o termo "Türkiye" e, embora a da [página](http://brasilia.emb.mfa.gov.tr/Mission) brasileira ainda não o faça, seus perfis nas redes sociais adotam amplamente o novo nome (e.g., [Twitter](https://twitter.com/TurkEmbBrazil) e [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/TurkEmbBrazil/about)).

No que concerne à adoção do novo nome pelo restante do mundo, me parece provável uma repetição da situação da Costa do Marfim: nos anos 1980 o país [teria pedido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivory_Coast#Etymology) oficialmente que apenas seu nome em francês, *Côte D'Ivoire*, fosse utilizado em todas as línguas — contudo até hoje versões traduzidas de seu nome permanecem dominantes em diversos países, com o nome oficial restrito ao uso protocolar.

Quanto à pronúncia de "Türkiye", ela é exemplificada neste [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Skq62zB750Y). Não acho muito diferente do português "Turquia", no máximo talvez com o "a" às vezes pronunciado mais como um "e".

Comment: In English, it's gonna be: Turkiye, no umlaut.

Comment: @Lambie, says who? [In a NPR news](https://www.npr.org/2023/01/08/1147704945/the-state-department-will-begin-spelling-turkey-as-turkiye) that cites [the US State Department](https://www.state.gov/briefings/department-press-briefing-january-5-2023/), it says that «the State Department will begin spelling Turkey as Türkiye».

Comment: @ANeves In my experience, that may be the official name but generally names with accents not used in English, are not used. For example: The U.S. Consulate General in **Sao Paulo**, as part of the U.S. Mission in Brazil seeks to protect the well-being of U.S. citizens, represent U.S. interests, promote better bilateral relations, and foster friendship between the people of our two countries. https://br.usembassy.gov/embassy-consulates/saopaulo/ So they say it, but people will not use the umlaut in practice.

Comment: Lambie, and yet [the equivalent Türkiye page](https://tr.usembassy.gov/embassy-consulates/) uses the umlauts consistently. It might fade with time, and I have the same opinion as you that common use will not adopt the umlaut. But the official US use has adopted the umlaut and I don't think that will change. In reality, it's not about an umlaut, not "just an accent": ü and u are two _different_ letters of their alphabet, like the infamous "Turkish test" letters iİ and ıI (i with dot, upper case I with dot, i without dot, uppercase i without dot), and I think that's where the request comes from.

Comment: Joke: Does anyone have Erdogan's contact? Maybe I'll ask them to keep the inertia and convince the international community to drop the idiotic O from "Oporto"... -_-

Comment: @ANeves Wow, I had never heard of "Oporto" until now. Maps in English seem to only use "Porto", Wikipedia in English and German redirects "Oporto" to "Porto", in many other languages it also seem to be called "Porto"... maybe it's a Spanish thing to call it "Oporto"? Maybe you only need to talk to your neighbor after all... ;-)

Comment: @stafusa Well, WP redirects to Porto but still uses "Oporto" throughout the article, the airport's code is OPO, etc. But it's changing over time! ❤ _Nuestros hermanos_ gave us a lot of trouble, but this one is not on them.

Comment: @ANeves Tens razão, não havia lido o verbete e não tinha mesmo notado - "oporto" aparece umas 80 vezes, "porto", umas 240. Segundo a versão alemã, o "o" é comum em inglês e espanhol (e um pouco em alemão).

Answer (score 2):

> mas fico pensando se o mesmo vale para o Português?

Acho que nem para o português nem para muitas outras linguas. O problema de pretender impor uma grafia por decreto a paises terceiros (reparem que a notícia diz: **"ordenaram"**) é que a Turquia não tem soberania nesses paises e nem sobre a grafia que é usada nesses paises.

Reparem que na palavra:

> Türkiye

Há duas consoantes (*k* e *y*) que costumamos chamar "estrangeiras" e ainda o trema (***ü***) que em Portugal nunca se usou e segundo o que percebi deixou de ser usado no Brasil após o último acordo ortográfico. Isto levante o problema de não sabermos com que pronúnica ler a palavra ortografica.

Alias, para grande parte dos paises existem duas grafias em português, por exemplo: Cambodja vs Camboja, Cosovo vs Kosovo, Omã vs Omão, Quénia vs Quênia, etc...

Segundo a notícia pretendem impor a grafia em paises que usam [alfabeto latino](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_latino) - acho que em paises que nem sequer usam o alfabeto latino ninguém ia achar a exigência aceitável.

O que a Turquia pretende parece ser mais político (a ideia de pretender "impor" uma grafia no estrangeiro deve ser agradável a uma parte do eleitorado) do que uma estratégia de marketing (*"branding"*) para reforçar a sua própria marca.

O mais engraçado é que um dos argumentos usados é não gostarem de ser *perus* (*turkeys* em inglês) (está na notícia DW linkada na pergunta):

> The association with the large, North American turkey — a bird that is typically served for dinner at Thanksgiving or Christmas — **has been a sore point for Turkish officials**.

Isto faz lembrar aquela piada de perguntarem qual o país cujo nome se pode comer e em vez de dizerem: Ja-***pão*** responderem **Cu**-ba... Suponho que sejam da Hungria, que em inglês se diz ***Hung***(a)***ry***...

Enfim, parece que vamos ter de aprender a [***grugulejar***](https://dicionario.priberam.org/grugulejar)...

Comment: Related: https://www.change.org/p/change-the-name-of-the-bird-turkey-to-t%C3%BCrkiye